# Install GLX 1.3 on Ubuntu 16.04.1 (Google Chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, opengl, mesa

I'm running a Ubuntu 16.04.1 (VM) and when using X11 forwarding I'm receiving the following error when launching google chrome (Note: Google chrome eventually launches, but I still would like to fix this error):

```
[4244:4244:1221/093216:ERROR:gl_surface_glx.cc(411)] GLX 1.3 or later is required.
[4244:4244:1221/093216:ERROR:gl_initializer_x11.cc(130)] GLSurfaceGLX::InitializeOneOff failed.
[4244:4244:1221/093216:ERROR:gpu_child_thread.cc(328)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
```

I've tried installing the latest mesa packages offered by this ppa, but still no luck. Anyone have any ideas?

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

GLX is still reporting at version 1.2

I'm not super familiar with the mesa libraries and how they work, but i'm running the latest as far as I can tell:

```
cj@ubuntu:/lib/modules$ dpkg -l | grep mesa
ii  libegl1-mesa:amd64                         13.0.1+git20161127+13.0.f7b58a37-0ubuntu0ricotz~xenial amd64        free implementation of the EGL API -- runtime
ii  libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64                      13.0.1+git20161127+13.0.f7b58a37-0ubuntu0ricotz~xenial amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- DRI modules
ii  libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64                      13.0.1+git20161127+13.0.f7b58a37-0ubuntu0ricotz~xenial amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX runtime
ii  libglapi-mesa:amd64                        13.0.1+git20161127+13.0.f7b58a37-0ubuntu0ricotz~xenial amd64        free implementation of the GL API -- shared library
ii  libglu1-mesa:amd64                         9.0.0-2.1                                              amd64        Mesa OpenGL utility library (GLU)
ii  libwayland-egl1-mesa:amd64                 13.0.1+git20161127+13.0.f7b58a37-0ubuntu0ricotz~xenial amd64        implementation of the Wayland EGL platform -- runtime
ii  mesa-utils                                 8.3.0-1                                                amd64        Miscellaneous Mesa GL utilities
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sudo ppa-purge xorg-edgers
```

...

```
$ sudo -E add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

...

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libvulkan-dev libvulkan1
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,558 kB of archives.
After this operation, 5,443 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 208248 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libvulkan-dev_1.1.73+dfsg-1~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libvulkan-dev:amd64 (1.1.73+dfsg-1~gpu18.04.1) over (1.1.70+dfsg1-1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libvulkan1_1.1.73+dfsg-1~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libvulkan1:amd64 (1.1.73+dfsg-1~gpu18.04.1) over (1.1.70+dfsg1-1) ...
Setting up libvulkan1:amd64 (1.1.73+dfsg-1~gpu18.04.1) ...
Setting up libvulkan-dev:amd64 (1.1.73+dfsg-1~gpu18.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
```

Upgrade works fine, but still in 1.2 (*OpenGL version string: 3.1 Mesa 19.0.8*)

```
$ sudo glxinfo | grep "GLX version"
GLX version: 1.2
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to AskUbuntu. Can you please add some more information to your answer? Why is the purging of the ppa needed?

Comment: Here is a part of the output :

`$ sudo -E add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
 == Xorg packages fresh from git ==

Currently supported releases are Xenial/16.04 and Yakkety/16.10

* WARNING: Do not use this PPA with enabled HWE stack.

Be sure to revert this PPA before doing a release upgrade or the upgrade will not succeed. To revert to official packages, install the ppa-purge package and run "sudo ppa-purge xorg-edgers".

== Important notice ==`

So I install the ppa-purge package and do the purge to have a "clean state".

Answer (score 0):

With `sudo apt-get update` you are not actually installing anything. After that you might want to run `sudo apt-get upgrade` to actually update the packages that the PPA has different versions for.